# Erase part of a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect

I've got a `mainView`, where I'm drawing lets say a picture in the background. `mainView` also have 3 `subviews`, which can be dragged onto each other. The `subviews` are squares with `clearColor` background and `redColor` frame. The problem is that if one view is dragged onto second view, I can see 2nd view 'below' 1st view. I'd like to erase it (only the part, which is overlapping), but have no idea how to do it. I'm presenting it on the screenshot below.

On the left there is current situation, on the right - desired one. Is it possible to erase part of subview..?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very custom effects like this are sometimes easier to do in one view's `-drawRect` method because otherwise the bordered rect that is partially erased needs to know about the other view. Draw the bottom rect's border, then erase the top rect, then draw the top rect's border. You may also be able to use multiple CGLayers with blending to achieve a similar effect with a bit more abstraction.

Comment: I've simplified the whole idea, in reality these subviews are rather complicated, everything is drawn in `drawRect`. I wouldn't like to merge it to one view, because it'll get very messy. That's why I'm asking about erasing the subview. Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your views could know about each-other then, and also use drawRect to erase the area of each other view above them, translated into local coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a clear color background, that's transparent, which is why your views are peeking through.  Change it to [UIColor whiteColor].

Comment: But I've written in the question that my background has a gradient. I don't want any white overlay nor any alpha value over it. With such idea I'd prefer subviews to peek through than have them white. This is not a solution but bypassing it without the fix.